# How to ensure user see the images pertaining to him only from private blob Azure Storage?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Some of the user’s images are stored in Azure BLOB which is not publicly accessible. In our scenario we upload the images (user’s images) on private blob which later needs to be shown at the client side(Angular). Moreover the user should only be able to see the images that is related to him and not the images of other users.

We can generate the list of images URLs at server side but when this is passed to client side to render, it would fail naturally being blob not being public.

Now, being all the users who would access the application are internal to the organization, I believe authorization to access the images can be achieved by AAD/SAS. However at the same time, I am fail to understand how would I ensure or apply the security that if wanted user X should not be able to read the images of user Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the issue, you can use the following suggestions to implement it.

1. Store the users information and their image information (such as the image's azure blob container name, azure blob blob name) in the database.
2. When the user wants to access the image, query the database with the users information to get the image.
3. After getting the image information, use the SDK to create a SAS token then return the image's blob url with sas token to the client. Regarding how to create sas token, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-service-sas-create-dotnet?tabs=dotnet).

Comment: Thanks Jim for your suggestion, this is simply great. Just in case, if you can provide any reference/example to generate SAS token via AAD.

Comment: @TarunNarang If we want to create sas token, we should use account key to do that. So Could you please tell me what you mean ` generate SAS token via AAD`?

Comment: AAD is Azure Active Directory. I got a link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview to work on this.

Comment: Regarding this, one last thing I wanted to confirm, After point 3 above, When the Image Blob's url with SAS token is send by the browser to Blob storage to fetch the image, Does the blob storage authorize the token, to ensure, the user for which the token was issued is the same user who is sending the request to fetch the image. In other words, if this token is compromised, then can anyone with this token view the results.

Comment: @TarunNarang When you create the SAS token, you add the user IP address. After doing that, If the IP address from which the request originates does not match the IP address  on the SAS token, the request is not authorized : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#specifying-ip-address-or-ip-range

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between "*Public*", and "*Anonymous*" access and confusing these two concepts is very common among the cloud developers.

**Anonymous access** to blob means that the images or objects on the blob can be accessed without authentication.
While **Public access** to a blob means accessing it from the internet.

The answer above is the right solution for protecting an object that is reachable via the internet. Use SAS tokens.
But if your storage account is not publicly accessible, then you can download the image (using the app identity) but not showing it in the browser directly even with SAS because that requires the internet. I assume the user in not an internal user in the network.
If you are concerned about the second scenario, I am thinking of downloading or caching the image by the application and showing it in the browser that does not require internet access to the image on the storage account but internet access to the cached version or copy. You can use a viewer, or you can create your own mechanism.

## Update: Real code examples**

**Note**: Please note that since I am using the application identity in my examples, this code is not handling the separation between users, this should be handled using the application itself. 
It's true that the SAS can handle that, but the second scenario will require application-level authorization.

**Scenario 1 (Access with SAS via public internet):**

Create a Service with these methods:

```
    public async Task<Uri> GetBlobUriWithSas(string blobName, int expiresInMinutes)
    
     {
         if (blobName == null) return null;
         var blobServiceUri = new Uri($"https://{StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net");
         var blobContainerUri = new Uri($"https://{StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{GetContainerName()}");
         BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobContainerUri, new DefaultAzureCredential());
         BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
         BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobServiceUri, new DefaultAzureCredential());
    
         var userDelegationKey = await RequestUserDelegationKey(blobServiceClient, expiresInMinutes);
         var uri = await CreateUserDelegationSASBlob(blobClient, userDelegationKey, expiresInMinutes);
         return uri;
     }

 private async Task<Uri> CreateUserDelegationSASBlob(BlobClient blobClient, UserDelegationKey userDelegationKey, int sasLifetimeInMinutes)
 {
     BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
     {
         BlobContainerName = blobClient.BlobContainerName,
         BlobName = blobClient.Name,
         Resource = "b",
         StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
         ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(sasLifetimeInMinutes)
     };

     // Specify the necessary permissions
     sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);

     // Add the SAS token to the blob URI
     BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(blobClient.Uri)
     {
         // Specify the user delegation key
         Sas = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(userDelegationKey, StorageAccountName)
     };

     return blobUriBuilder.ToUri();
 }


 private async Task<UserDelegationKey> RequestUserDelegationKey(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient, int sasLifetimeInMinutes)
 {
     UserDelegationKey userDelegationKey =
         await blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKeyAsync(
             DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
             DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(sasLifetimeInMinutes));

     return userDelegationKey;
 }
```

And in the UI part, the is the view , you type something like this:

```
   @{
       var diagramUri = await BlobStorageService.GetBlobUriWithSas(Model?.AttachmentViewModel?.BlobName);
       <img src=@diagramUri class="img-thumbnail" itemtype="http://schema.org/Photograph">
   }
```

**Scenario 2 (Access Image on without the internet)**

You need this method:

```
  public async Task<string> RetrieveImageUrl(string blobName)
  {
      var blobContainerUri = new Uri($"https://{StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{GetContainerName()}");
      try
      {
          BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(blobContainerUri, new DefaultAzureCredential());
          var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
          BlobDownloadResult blobDownloadResult = await blobClient.DownloadContentAsync();
          byte[] imageBinaryData = blobDownloadResult.Content.ToArray();
          string imagebase64Data = imageBinaryData.ToBase64String();
          string imageformattedData = $"data:image/png;base64,{imagebase64Data}";
          return imageformattedData;
      }
      catch (Exception exception)
      {
          Logger.LogError(exception, $"Exception in {nameof(RetrieveImageUrl)}");
          return ExceptionWhileRetrieve;
      }
  }
```

And in the UI, do the following of something similar:

```
 @{
     var diagramUri = await BlobStorageService.RetrieveImageUrl(Model?.AttachmentViewModel?.BlobName);
     <img src=@diagramUri class="img-thumbnail" itemtype="http://schema.org/Photograph">
 }
```

Comment: fyi there is no need for posting a code sample, as 1) the OP didn't ask for one or provide any code of their own; and 2) an accepted answer was posted 4 years ago. There is no programming question here to answer.